# How to parse an AWS S3 file from a Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, readline

I need some help with correctly structuring the code for process some text files using S3 buckets and a Lambda function.

I want to use a Lambda function triggered by creation of a new object in the S3 bucket to read the file and to extract some data and write this to a file that gets placed in another S3 bucket.

So far I have the function working fine copying the file from one S3 bucket to another but I can't quite figure out how to add a function to process the file and write the result out to the final S3 destination.

The files are simple text files and I need to extract data from each line in the file.

Below if the Node.js code I am currently using with an additional function added to process the file - see comments with ?? where I am looking for help.

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var util = require('util');


// get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  
    var dstBucket = "inputBucket";
    var dstKey    = srcKey + ".txt";

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        console.error("Destination bucket must not match source bucket.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the file type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        console.error('unable to infer file type for key ' + srcKey);
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "txt") {
        console.log('skipping non-image ' + srcKey);
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the file from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            // Read the file we have just downloaded 
            // ? response.Body ?
            var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
                input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
            });

            // Process each line here writing the result to an output buffer?
            rl.on('line', function (line) {
                 console.log('Line from file:', line);
                //Do something with the line... 

                //Create some output string 'outputline'

                //Write 'outputline' to an output buffer 'outbuff'
                // ??

            });
            // Now pass the output buffer to the next function
            // so it can be uploaded to another S3 bucket 
            // ?? 
            next;
        }
        function upload(response, next) {
            // Stream the file to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: response.Body,
                    ContentType: response.contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to process ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully processed ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            context.done();
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: I don't know Node.js. But I have written a Lambda which does something like what you do but written in Python. I m not sure what exactly you are asking. I see the comments with ??. Do you need Node.js specific help or logic help?

Comment: @helloV Node.js specific help I think, but I could always use Python instead if you have a Python example doing the same.

Comment: @helloV I am looking for a python script that parses S3 object and remove first word of each line and copy it back to S3. Could you please share it if you still have the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the callback of s3.getObject

```
s3.getObject(params,function(err,data){})
```

If your file is a text then you can extract the text as a string

```
data.Body.toString("utf-8")
```